# Volume of a frustum with arbitary base area.

Tags: integration, geometry

How do I find the volume of the frustum of a cone which has base area $A_o$, top area $A_t$ and height $h$?

I am able to do this for circular and square bases, but unable to figure it out for arbitrary surfaces.

Can someone give me an idea of how to do this rigorously?

Comment: So what are your results for the circular and square bases?

Answer (score 0):

S is a cone and it has the characteristic of (H[the height], B[the base] and V[the volume]).

s, the cut-off part of a cone with the remaining part forming a frustum, is also a cone having the characteristic of (h, b, v).

Since S and s are similar objects, the relation of these parameters are

$V : v = H^3 : h^3$ and $B : b = H^2 : h^2$

From these relations, we can deduce the volume of the frustum, which is V – v.